# how to generate table with numbers from range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to generate a table with numbers between 0 and 9999 in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE digits (digit CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO digits VALUES ('0'), ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9');
```

Comment: Do not store numbers as strings. And you can't fit `9999` in a `char(1)` column anyway (You also shouldn't use the `char` type at all)

Comment: i know, but @a_horse_with_no_name when was corrected, he removed suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Just use `generate_series()`.  I prefer it in the `from` clause so:

```
select gs.val
from generate_series(0, 9999) gs(val);
```

However, Postgres does not require the `from` clause, so you can do:

```
select generate_series(0, 9999) as val;
```

Comment: That's not what I expected

Comment: @kornelkornel . . . This answers the question that you asked.  It is the best way to do this in Postgres.

Comment: you don't understand my question, becouse I'm not looking bast way. I must use this code in question

Answer (score 0):

Donno why you are using `CHAR` as the digit column type, but if you have to, these insertion works:

`INSERT INTO digits VALUES (to_char(generate_series(0, 9999), 'FM9999'));`

Comment: That's not what I expected